# Angular 2: Work with Observable and return Observable

Tags: angular, observable

I have a question to angular2 and observables.
In a service i want to work with an observable (loaded from another service) and then return data as an observable, too.

How can i do this?
I have this code:

```
getEPGDayByChannel(channelID, newDate) {
        let mydate = new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), newDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);


            let fromDate = new Date(mydate.getFullYear(), mydate.getMonth(), mydate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
            let endDate = new Date(mydate.getFullYear(), mydate.getMonth(), mydate.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
            this.apiService.getChannelEPGbyTime(channelID, fromDate, endDate).
            subscribe(
            data => {
                //do some magic with the data
                // return some thing of the data as an observable
                return Observable.of(data.programme);
            },
            error => { this.variables.setFailure(error);}
            );

     }
```

But with this code i get this failure:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.epgService.getEPGDayByChannel(...) is undefined

Unhandled Promise rejection: this.epgService.getEPGDayByChannel(...) is undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: this.epgService.getEPGDayByChannel(...) is undefined
```

I would be very pleased for some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
getEPGDayByChannel(channelID, newDate) {
    let mydate = new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), newDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);


    let fromDate = new Date(mydate.getFullYear(), mydate.getMonth(), mydate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
    let endDate = new Date(mydate.getFullYear(), mydate.getMonth(), mydate.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);

    return this.apiService.getChannelEPGbyTime(channelID, fromDate, endDate)
        .map(data => {
            //do some magic with the data
            // return some thing of the data as an observable
            return data.programme;
        })
        .catch(error => { 
            this.variables.setFailure(error);
        });

 }
```

Comment: really, so simple?? :D
It´s all ok, thank you so much!
Spent the whole day with this^^
Thanks!

Comment: @Junias Yes, it's that simple. But you need to understand that the `apiService.getChannelEPGbyTime` doesn't get called as soon as you call your `getEPGDayByChannel` method, but only when you subscribe to it. Your code did call the apiService just by calling it, without subscribing.